# Sending files from android app to Azure VM

Tags: android, azure, virtual-machine

I am buidling an app which requires the transfer of files from the android app in question to an Windows based Azure VM. What should I do to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, it's too broad because there are many ways to make this possible. An usual way is that creating a web server and receiving the files via a HTTP request of POST or PUT method to store into a specified directory on the VM.